# Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, emulador

Instalei Visual Studio com Xamarin, SDK do Android, etc.

Quando vou compilar o projeto ele abre o AVD do Android, mas o Sistema do Android não carrega, fica só uma tela preta.

Comment: Tenta rodar no device que o VS cria pra você, escolha a opção x64x86

Comment: Essa que escolho, mas fica so a tela preta e nada. Se eu inicio manualmente ele (o que o VS cria), no máximo fica aparecendo o logo do Android e nada....

Comment: Entendi, seu computador tem os requisitos mínimos pra rodar o emulador?

Comment: Sim, Roda normal via Android Studio

Comment: Tente utilizar o visual studio emulator for android.

Comment: @Luhhh, tive esse problema e utilizei a CPU Atom x86. Recomendo essa configuracao pois é mais rápida, sendo necessário instalar o Intel HAXM através do website da Intel.

Comment: Verificou a janela output do Visual Studio? Poderia colocar uma imagem representando o problema? Coloque mais detalhes sobre o seu problema para que seja mais fácil ajudá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava tendo muitos problemas com o emulador do android no Mac, baixei então o plugin do **Genymotion** e finalmente resolvi os problemas quanto ao android.

Hoje em dia estou usando tanto no windows (no trabalho) quanto em casa (mac) o plugin deles.

Da uma olhada [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: uma outra solução possível seria instalar intel haxm e fazer um avd com x86